# Prevent some components from re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react-hooks. So there is a modal that pops up with a bunch of inputs (components) like text fields, drop-downs, date pickers and etc...
The problem is when some field is being edited, all my form components are being re-rendered and that makes my form very slow. I totally understand why it happens. However, I would like to find a way when I edit some input within my form, all other input fields (components) should stay "frozen" and not re-rendered. Otherwise, working with my form which has at least 20 input fields, would make the work very slow...

Your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: better share minimal reproducable example. you see, for React it's ok to re-render components on change happen and typically(especially for form controls that usually are not really complex) it is not an issue at all. so before suggesting using `React.memo` or hooks aimed on performance optimization it's better to check if issue is not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). It doesn't use setState, so it won't be re-rendered when you type some input value. Then you can send everything when you submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using React.memo which is in some way an equivalent to shouldComponentUpdate

[Check React.memo documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)